# Filter members Discord JS

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I want to create a "filter member" like, I type "!filter Lio" and the bot map all members with "Lio" or "lio" in their username or nickname and he send in the console all of the member with the "Lio" or "lio" in their username or nickname. I worked harder for find this but I don't really how to do. Thanks you for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track; you would use [`Collection.prototype.filter()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/general/welcome).

```js
// `guild` is a placeholder for the guild object
// `name` is a placeholder for the user input
guild.members.cache.filter(
 (m) =>
  m.username.toLowerCase().includes(name) ||
  m.displayName.toLowerCase().includes(name)
);
```

Comment: Can you send an exemple of the code please like 

const name = ...

Comment: I did show an example of the code, it's your job to apply it to your project.

Comment: Because I have a problem, I have the collection output in json but I don't know how to remove the collection outpout like this :

Collection [Map] {
  'id => GuildMember {
    guild: Guild {
      (infos)
    },
    user: User {
      (infos)
    },
    (infos)
  }

Comment: I just want the user.username

Comment: [`Collection.prototype.first()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=first)